# Is this a new kind of liar puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-identification, liars

I would like to ask if anyone has seen elsewhere this variation on the standard truth tellers/liars kind of puzzle.

In the usual repertoire it is assumed that every person questioned knows the answer to every question asked.  We now assume that this need not be the case; and that if a truth-teller is asked a question to which he does not know the answer, he will truthfully reply "I don't know", while a liar will never admit to not knowing.

This can still be formulated in various ways: here is a specific example and a puzzle.

(But **please note**: my question is not to solve the puzzle but to ask if anyone has seen anything like it before.)

---

In a certain town each of the inhabitants is either a truth-teller or a liar; however this does not mean that everyone is actually able to answer every question they are asked.  If a truth-teller is absolutely certain of the answer to a question, he will give that answer; if not, he will say, "I don't know."  On the other hand, a liar will never truthfully admit to not knowing something: he will give an answer that he knows is false, if any, but if there is nothing that he is *certain* is false then he will give a randomly chosen answer (possibly even, by accident, the true answer).  Moreover, everyone in this town can instantly deduce the logical consequences of any facts they know.

I meet four inhabitants of this town and ask them, "How many of you four are truth-tellers?"

Kevin says, "I don't know"; then Laura says, "One"; then Mike says, "None."  Noela, however, is asleep.  Fortunately I don't need to wake her up, since I can already tell whether she is a truth-teller or a liar.  Which?

Comment: No, I have not.:)

Comment: What is your goal in asking? Did you make this puzzle, and you want feedback regarding originality? Do you want to find more like this because you thought this was interesting? Also, if this isn't yours, you should probably tell us where it came from.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop Came up with it myself, would like feedback regarding originality.  Can you help?

Comment: Well, I can tell you that I've never seen exactly that setup, and that it adds an extra level of complexity to the standard puzzle type. However, I don't think anyone will be able to confidently tell you that there are none like it. If puzzling is made up of truth tellers, the only answer will be "I don't know".

Comment: While this is definitely an interesting puzzle, I'm not sure it will generate helpful answers as it's worded. It is highly probable that someone, somewhere, at some point in time, has thought of something similar. The answer to "Is it original?" is, honestly, "Nobody really knows," that is, unless someone finds a duplicate. But this being an original puzzle with original wording, that is a difficult task. Is there a way you can think of to reword this to generate more helpful answers?

Comment: @Emrakul thanks for the comment but I think I am asking exactly what I want to know.  And if I don't get any "yes" answers, that will in itself be an answer of a kind ;-)

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop thanks for that.  I appreciate that I can't expect any definite "no" answers, but there is the possibility that someone will be able to give me a reference to somewhere where this problem, or something similar, has already appeared.

Comment: One clarification it could use - will liars ever say "I don't know"? You say they "will never truthfully admit to not knowing", but that leaves it ambiguous as to whether or not they will say "I don't know" when they do in fact know.

Comment: Since the example was never solved, I want to see it completed for future readers.  If only truthers say "i don't know", Noela must be a truth teller as Laura must have known 1 was false or she would have said 0.  If Kevin feigns ignorance, Noela could be either.  She could be a liar if Laura accurately states that she is the only truth teller.

Comment: Hi @kaine, here is my solution.  A liar will never admit to not knowing, so Kevin must be a truth-teller.  Having heard this, Laura will also know that Kevin is a truth-teller.  If she is also a truth-teller then she knows that the answer to my question is 2, or 3, or 4, or she doesn't know.  In no case would she give the answer 1.  So Laura is a liar.  Mike also knows that Kevin is a truth-teller, so Mike has given a false answer and is a liar... to be continued

Comment: ...Now suppose that Noela is a liar.  Then Laura would have given the right answer: as she is a liar, the only way this could happen is if she didn't know any *definitely* false answer.  But this is not the case: she knew that Kevin was a truth-teller and therefore that "None" would have been a false answer.  It must therefore be that Noela is a truth-teller (and that Laura knew this, and therefore knew that "One" was a false answer).

Comment: @RobWatts sorry I didn't reply earlier, for some reason I didn't get notified of your comment.  In my scenario (of course it is possible to make up different scenarios) a liar will never admit to not knowing.  I should have left out the word "truthfully" to make this more clear.  Thanks!

Comment: I have heard of questions like this, but they didn't have loopholes like this one.
Can a liar say I don't know? There are too many explainable answers, more than one answer is not right for this type of puzzle.

Comment: "Can a liar say I don't know?", that is answered: "while a liar will never admit to not knowing.", and there is only one answer to the puzzle.

Comment: Hmmm. Thats embarrassing :).

Comment: @eBusiness a liar is not admitting he doesn't know if he actually does know but says he doesn't

Comment: But that'll make it too easy then. Because of what can be seen in your answer also. Hearing somebody answering "I don't know" immediately puts him as the truth-teller and this also immediately puts Mike as a liar, which might make the puzzle less interesting,

Comment: @justhalf I would be interested if you can give a simpler solution than mine to the question of whether Noela is a liar.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually Laura can answer "One" also when she does not know what Noela is, right? Noela can as well be a liar, then.

Comment: @justhalf No.  Read the condition more carefully.  If Laura does not know what Noela is then she does not know for sure that "one" is a false answer, and therefore will not give this answer.

Comment: But the condition also says `if there is nothing that he is certain is false then he will give a randomly chosen answer (possibly even, by accident, the true answer)`. "One" is a possibility in the random choice, right?

Comment: @justhalf But in Laura's case there **is** an answer which she is certain is false, namely "none", and therefore she will not make a random choice.  Please read my solution in comments above.

Comment: I see, then as evidenced by this rather not-so-short discussion, the riddle is interesting. :) Perhaps you can make the description more interesting and less ambiguous by stating "the liars are very proud of themselves, and they never want to say that they don't know". Using the word "admit" suggests that the liars won't say "I don't know" when they indeed don't know, but that ambiguously left some people thinking that the liars might still say "I don't know" when they actually know something.

Comment: @justhalf Thanks for the comment.  I will remove the word "truthfully" as recommended above by Rob Watts.  May well incorporate some of your suggestions too.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining a situation in which a liar can _not_ give a known-to-be-false answer. For instance, in the example given, "five" would be a false answer too (as well as, arguably, "nitwit", "blubber", "oddment", and "tweak").

Comment: If the correct answer has been provided below, don't forget to $\color{green}{\text{Accept}}\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$ it! :)

Answer (score 6):

Kevin = "I don't know"    == True (Because he truthfully said, that he didn't know)

Laura = "One"             == False (Because if she says truth, then there would be at least 2 truth tellers as Kevin is already a truth teller).

Mike = "None."            == False (Because Kevin proves himself a truth teller)

Noela =                   == True (Because if Noela is False then there is only 1 (i.e. Kevin) and Laura also replied "One" and we know that Laura is false)

Hence, there are Two out of Four Truth-Tellers in town.

Now, I do remembered such a kind of question in a book titled as "Discrete Mathematics and its Applications" Author: "Kenneth H. Rosen" Ed:"7th".

Comment: Could you site what was in the book?  P.S. Note - the OP said explicitly "my question is not to solve the puzzle", so the solution is offtopic here. P.P.S. your solution is not complete, see the comments to the question.

Comment: @waqas Can you give me a page reference to the question in Rosen?  Much appreciated.

Comment: yes but in the scenario that laura is a liar noela could be a liar.It just happens that laura said one by luck, giving the correct answer accidentaly

Comment: @libathos OP specifies that if the liar has answers that she knows are false then she will give one of those answers.  Laura had the option to answer zero and did not.

Comment: @Taemyr how do you know that Laura knows that there are 2 truth tellers?

Comment: @Cephalopod Remember that as a liar Laura will always, if possible, choose an answer that she knows to be false.  If Laura did not know that there where excactly 2 truth tellers there was a chance that only one 1 truth tellers.  This means that after she answers 1 we know that she knows that there are more than 1 truth teller, because she had the option to answer 0 or 5, both of which she would know to be false.